# How to print all the subdirectories in a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

In this code, I am trying to print the all the subdirectories and count them. But when I run this code, it gives me the following result.

**Given result**

```
Total directories: 1
['/home/runner/TestP1/.upm']
Total directories: 2
['/home/runner/TestP1/.upm', '/home/runner/TestP1/folder1']
Total directories: 3
['/home/runner/TestP1/.upm', '/home/runner/TestP1/folder1', '/home/runner/TestP1/folder2']
```

**Expected result**

```
Total directories: 3
['/home/runner/TestP1/.upm', '/home/runner/TestP1/folder1', '/home/runner/TestP1/folder2']
```

**Code**

```
import os

subDir = []
def listdirs(path, count):
  for roots, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for dir in dirs:
      d = os.path.join(roots, dir)
      subDir.append(d)
      count = len(subDir)
      print(f"Total directories: {count}")
      print(subDir)

rootdir = '/home/runner/TestP1'
count = 0
listdirs(rootdir, count)
```

Comment: check os.listdir()

Comment: Somebody say use `os.walk` and some say use `os.listdir`

Comment: `os.walk()` examines an entire directory tree; `os.listdir()` only examines the current directory.  It's not clear from your question which of these behaviors you want.

Comment: I want to examine an entire directory tree. Now will you please help me with this?

Comment: You are printing inside the loop; if you only want to print when the loop is done, remove indentation from the `print`. If you can't figure this out by yourself, probably try to produce a [mre] rather than post code you didn't write yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Printing the total directories outside your loop works. Check it out :)

```
import os

subDir = []
def listdirs(path, count):
  for roots, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for dir in dirs:
      d = os.path.join(roots, dir)
      subDir.append(d)
      count = len(subDir)
  print(f"Total directories: {count}")
  print(subDir)  

rootdir = '/home/runner/TestP1'
count = 0
listdirs(rootdir, count)
```